# return boolean based on comparision

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have to return a boolean value based on comparision

```
fn:compare("12", "11")
```

If `output is >1` then true 
if `output is <=0` then false

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to compare the stringified numbers as numbers, or as strings?

If you want to compare them as numbers, just do:

```
fn:number("12") > fn:number("11")
```

If you want to compare them as strings, do:

```
fn:compare("12", "11") > 0
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons in XQuery do return booleans:

```
(12 > 1) => true()
```

If you have string input, then cast them as numbers before making the comparison:

```
(xs:integer("12") > xs:integer("1")) => true()
```